# How to write wrapper for merging odata services

Tags: graph, odata, semantic-web

[image]We have recently started integrating with few odata services with a goal to integrate around 50+ different vendors all through odata. Their structure might be different but all of them are providing same or similar data (for some we have to tokenize couple of fields).

Naive way is to integrate all of them, create mappers for all 50, query all and merge the data back. We need to deduplicate in the process. 
I am thinking if there is a better way to implement this system which is bit loosely coupled on mapping part, may be a good idea if the system can figure out mapping itself.

I have been researching on semantic web, to create an ontology as what is being called as what in different vendors etc, but couldn't justify the way to integrate with odata.

Any ideas or criticism are highly appreciated. Feel free to ask any info.